# Arabic HTML layout direction with css

Tags: html, css, layout

To change the text direction to right to left it is known that we the following CSS code:

```
direction:rtl; //displays text direction as right to left
```

Is there any way in css to invert the total page layout direction to right to left including lists ?

Comment: The `direction` property does *not* change text direction; it sets the layout direction. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-direction So you need to specify what you want to do that is *not* covered by this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add dir="rtl" to the html tag any time the overall document direction is right-to-left. This sets the base direction for the whole document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
```

Answer (score 4):

This wil RTL everything in the page:

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<p>معادن</p>
<ol>
  <li>ذهب</li>
  <li>فضة</li>
  <li>حديد</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```css
body 
{direction:rtl;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is likely to use a CSS processor tool similar to [Google's CSS Janus](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2008/03/cssjanus-helping-i18n-and-ltr-to-rtl.html); this type of tool does several things to flip a site's CSS from left-to-right oriented to right-to-left oriented, including adding direction:rtl, but also flipping left/right position and size values - so, for example, a DIV placed 4px from the left edge of its parent ends up instead being placed 4px from the right.

This means you'll end up with two stylesheets for your site: the original one, to use in left-to-right version, and a processed version to use in the right-to-left version.