# Convert website layout left to right into right to left

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.5

want to develop a website in Arabic or in English language, according to language i want to change the layout of the website, when user click on English website layout becomes left to right and on Arabic website layout should become right to left, i am doing it in Laravel please help me.

Comment: use css for right to left.

Comment: how it convert all div and section when user change the language , can you please give me demo ?

Comment: My proposition is to use additional styles different for each language which do the job. You will detect on your layout.blade which language is and include proper style

Comment: @Arslan Akram, see this. it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249466/arabic-html-layout-direction-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dir="rtl"` and `dir="ltr"` as shown below in HTML

For Arabic use below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and for English:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: can  you please tell me how i can covert translation on dynamic data in laravel ?

Comment: @ArslanAkram this solution is for only layout direction not for data translation. you need Localization for that

Answer (score 0):

I'n new here, hope this helps, this is how you would do it in js

```
<p id="demo" align="center"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    function changeToEnglish() {
        document.getElementById("demo").align = "left";
    }
    function changeToArabic() {
        document.getElementById("demo").align = "right";
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="changeToEnglish()">English</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeToArabic()">Arabic</button>
```