# How to use both English and Persian in Wordpress posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website that uses either English or Persian in posts. The problem is that English is left to right while Persian is right to left. If I choose English and the site language, the English post look fine but the Persian posts, although right justified, end sentences on the right instead of the left. If I choose Persian as the site language, the Persian text displays correctly, but the English text is right justified and the sentences end with a period on the left. How do I get both languages to format correctly? I would prefer to be able to assign language right in the posts, but I don't see how to do that. Any sugestions?
I am using latest version of WordPress with a theme called Brilliant Plus by Design Lab.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249466/arabic-html-layout-direction-with-css

Comment: @Elman Yes, but the punctuation, like sentence ending periods, end up at the wrong side of the line. I did find a plugin for this issue, but it is only verified for 3.x versions of WordPress. I'm trying it but it hasn't been updated in years. Thanks

Comment: Which plugin is it?

Comment: Weglot Translate v3.1.6. My Farsi speaking client says the translation is bad and asked me to remove it. Now trying Per Post Language v.1.3. Allows setting language inside each post or page. Seems to be working.